# Reducing db queries in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a view that searches through a database of movie credits, and converts and returns results like so --

```
# From the following results:
Avatar - James Cameron - director
Avatar - James Cameron - writer
Avatar - James Cameron - editor
Avatar - Julie Jones - writer
Crash - John Smith - director

# ...display in the template as:
Avatar - James Cameron (director, writer, editor)
Avatar - Julie Jones (writer)
Crash - John Smith (director)
```

However, when I do this conversion and do `print connection.queries` I am hitting the database about 100 times. Here is what I currently have --

```
# in models
class VideoCredit(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(VideoInfo)

    # if the credit is a current user, FK to his profile,
    profile = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', blank=True, null=True)
    # else, just add his name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    # normalize name for easier searching / pulling of name
    normalized_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    actor_role = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)    

class VideoInfo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    ...
```

class Position(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
        ...
```

In my view, I am building a list of three-tuples in the form of `(name, video, [list_of_positions])` for the display of credits --

```
    credit_set = VideoCredit.objects.filter(***depends on a previous function***)
    list_of_credit_tuples = []
    checklist = [] # I am creating a 'checklist' to see whether to append the positions
                   # list of create a new tuple entry
    for credit in credit_set:
        if credit.profile:  # check to see if the credit has an associated profile
            name = credit.profile    
        else:
            name = credit.normalized_name
        if (credit.normalized_name, credit.video) in checklist:
            list_of_keys = [(name, video) for name, video, positions in list_of_credit_tuples]
            index = list_of_keys.index((name, credit.video))
            list_of_credit_tuples[index][2].append(credit.position)
        else:
            list_of_credit_tuples.append((name, credit.video, [credit.position]))
            checklist.append((credit.normalized_name, credit.video))
    ...
```

And finally, in my template to display the credits (note: if the credit has a profile, provide a link to profile of user) --

```
{% for name, video, positions in list_of_credit_tuples %}
<p>{% if name.full_name %}
    <a href="{% url profile_main user_id=name.id %}">{{name.full_name}}</a>
    {% else %}
    {{name}}
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{% url videoplayer video_id=video.id %}">{{video}}</a>
    ({% for position in positions %}{% ifchanged %}{{position}}{% endifchanged %}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %})
{% endfor %}
```

Why and where is this view creating so many db queries? How and in which ways could I make this view function more efficient / better? Thank you.

Comment: I'm seeing an issue with list_of_keys = [(name, video) for name, video, positions in list_of_credit_tuples].  Why are you getting position and then ever using it?  You're also trying to iterate over a list that unless you've left something out is empty at this point

Comment: @John the reason I'm only checking against `(name, video)` and not `(name, video, position)` is because I want to create a list of all positions for that name-video pair. Does this answer what you were referring to, or is something different?

Comment: As I said below the answer to your actual problem is select related however: list_of_credit_tuples = [].  The next time list_of_credit_tuples is referenced is in the list comprehension.  That means in that branch of your if statement that is always going to be an empty list.  Unless you're setting it in some way you left out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will want to look into select_related() (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to resolve your query leaking issue.  If you know ahead of time you're going to be looking at data on models related by a foreignkey you'll want to add select_related.  Even better if you know it's only going to be a couple of foreignkeys you can add only the ones you need.

Anytime you see django ran a huge number of queries more than you expected, select_related is almost always the right answer

Comment: In addition to this, if you know that your DB is not changing rapidly, Caching is Your Friend™. I have one site where the author only posts about every 2 weeks, but when he does it causes all sorts of pages to change because of the relationships. We just cache the crap out of everything and, once we recompute the nasty pages, the site flies.

Comment: @John -- I added this using `select_related()` --        `credit_set = VideoCredit.objects.select_related(depth=1).filter(normalized_name__icontains=search)`, however it doesn't seem to be making much of a difference. Am I adding it to the right place?

Comment: Although what you have should work, try VideoCredit.objects.select_related('position').filter(normalized_name__icontains=search).  If that doesn't seem to help I'll need more information on exactly what the queries it's running are so I can look for a pattern.

Comment: @John, about the same result.

Comment: I can't see the queries so maybe I'm overlooking something else that is triggering a leak of queries.  I'd suggest django-debug-toolbar so that you can take a good look at what queries are really being run and how many times.  Look for patterns (nearly identical query being run many times)

Comment: +1 for select_related().  You can also use defer() and only() to keep your query down to the minimum if you know exactly what information you are going to need.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#defer

Comment: @John, thanks for the answer. Do you think the list comprehension in the view is a bad/expensive way to create the list of credits? Would there be a better/more efficient way?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this Django snippet which returns the number of queries as well as the queries themselves to your template:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/159/

This should easily tell you where your leak is originating from.